# What is the right way to define versionName as ext variable in Android build.gradle?

Tags: android, gradle, task, build.gradle

I tried to define versionName as an ext variable to be used in my gradle configuration file app/build.gradle.

```
ext {
    versionCode = 19
    versionName = "1.2.3"
    ...
}
...
android {
    ...
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        versionCode versionCode
        versionName versionName
    }
    ...
}
...
task updateReleaseMetadata(type:Exec) {
    commandLine 'sh'
    args "MyShellScript.sh", versionName
}
...
```

It seemed work fine. However my android code failed to retrieve the versionName as following

```
PackageInfo pi = context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(context.getPackageName(), 0);
return pi.versionName;  // return null
```

I think I had not use the gradle in the right way.
Any help would be appriciated.

Comment: Have tried tried setting versionCode 19 instead of using another variable inside your defaultConfig{}?

Comment: @Christian if I set "versionCode 19", my code worked fine. If I set "versionCode versionCode", pi.versionCode=0. It was the same as what I did with versionName.

Comment: posted my answer below. cheers!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is how to set a global variable in Gradle. Use this instead of ext {}

```
project.ext.set("versionCode", 19)
project.ext.set("versionName", "1.2.3")
```

Then in your defaultConfig

```
versionCode project.versionCode
versionName project.versionName
```

Comment: Two more questions: what is ext {} for? how can my ant {} block use the project.versionName? Thanks in advance for your continouse reply or a link to the official document.

Comment: You can refer to the Gradle official documentation 
https://gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.Project.html.

Comment: "Use this instead of ext {}" - Why?