# Setting android version code / name in gradle subproject from root project

Tags: android, gradle

In my sub-project that builds an android app, i'm attempting to set the version code / name based on variables in my root build.gradle.

sub-project `build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24

    // current atak build tools version"
    buildToolsVersion "28.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        multiDexEnabled true
        versionCode project.commit_head_count
        versionName project.full_version
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
}

// set the build info prior to building
build.dependsOn rootProject.setBuildInfo
```

root build.gradle:

```
// gathers git / build information and dumps it to VERSION files to be read by web app and data analysis program
task setBuildInfo() {
    doLast {
        // read the core version file and store in variable
        def coreVersionFile = new File("$projectDir/VERSION.txt")
        def coreVersion = coreVersionFile.readLines().get(0)

        // get the git hash value (short)
        def getShortGitHashCmd = "git rev-parse --short HEAD"
        def getShortGitHashProcess = getShortGitHashCmd.execute()

        // get the count of commits on this branch at HEAD
        def getCommitCountCmd = "git rev-list HEAD --count"
        def getCommitCountProcess = getCommitCountCmd.execute()

        ext.commit_head_count = getCommitCountProcess.text.trim()
        ext.git_hash = getShortGitHashProcess.text.trim()
        ext.full_version = "$coreVersion.$ext.commit_head_count"
        ext.build_date = new Date().format('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')

        // assigns the full_version for global use in other task
        // https://stackoverflow.com/a/29597784/680268
        project.ext.$full_version = ext.full_version
        project.ext.$commit_head_count = ext.commit_head_count


        def fileContent =
                "Short Version:$coreVersion\n" +
                        "Long Version:$ext.full_version\n" +
                        "Git hash:$ext.git_hash\n" +
                        "Commit count:$ext.commit_head_count\n" +
                        "Build date:$ext.build_date\n"
        print fileContent
    }
}

// set the build info prior to building
compileJava.dependsOn setBuildInfo
```

When this executes, the android app sub-project says that it doesn't know what the `commit_head_count` variable is referring to. I feel like if I could actually get `setBuildInfo` to run first, it would work,  but can't get that to work

Comment: hmm this properties doesn't exists at the sync time and that's where are used

Comment: what is "sync time". How do I resolve this?

Comment: it's when gradle is generating build tasks ... you should rather use `preBuild` instead `build` ... or not using task at all just plain methods

Comment: Use this syntax : `rootProject.ext.commit_head_count` same for other variables.

Comment: what does "use preBuild" mean? If I change prebuild.dependOn setBuldInfo, that doesn't work either.

Comment: @JeelVankhede do you mean to use that syntax in the subproject? I've tried that, but there's no change. setBuildInfo() still isn't executing at all.

Answer (score 0):

Use below code snippet to execute your custom task when some other task executed:

```
tasks.matching { it.name == 'name of dependent task (i.e build)' }.all { Task task ->
    task.dependsOn setBuildInfo
}
```

This would make all other matching tasks force to be dependent of your custom task.

Or other solution would be making your build info when project gets evaluated.

Put this code below in your root level **build.gradle** and check the result:

```
project.afterEvaluate {
    print("This line prints every single time")
}
```

Comment: While I haven't tried this specifically, all attempts to make the `build` task dependent on my root project's setBuildInfo() task doesn't cause it to execute first. the android{} tag seems to be evaluated first

Comment: You can check with if task name contains `:app:preBuild` or other thing to execute your task every time by executing your code inside `project.afterEvaluate { }` block.

Comment: OK, but setting a task to depend on setBulidInfo does nothing. I've also tried this in sub-proj, and it doesn't work: `preBuild.dependsOn rootProject.setBuildInfo`