# How can I provide a property for versionCode/versionName in a Gradle build

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle

I am trying to read versionCode and versionName from a properties file (which I seem to be able to do), and use those values when declaring the Android versionCode and versionName (which does not seem to work).

build.properties

```
versionCode=21001003
versionName=21.1.3-SNAPSHOT
```

build.gradle (working)

```
// Read from properties file into Extra properties
def props = new Properties()
file("build.properties").withInputStream { props.load(it) }
props.entrySet().each { it -> project.ext.setProperty((String) it.key, it.value) }

println 'project.versionCode=' + project.versionCode
println 'project.versionName=' + project.versionName
println 'project.ext.versionCode=' + project.ext.versionCode
println 'project.ext.versionName=' + project.ext.versionName

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        versionCode 1 //versionCode
        versionName "versionName"
    }
    ...
}
```

build.gradle (failing)

```
// Read from properties file into Extra properties
def props = new Properties()
file("build.properties").withInputStream { props.load(it) }
props.entrySet().each { it -> project.ext.setProperty((String) it.key, it.value) }

println 'project.versionCode=' + project.versionCode
println 'project.versionName=' + project.versionName
println 'project.ext.versionCode=' + project.ext.versionCode
println 'project.ext.versionName=' + project.ext.versionName

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        versionCode project.versionCode
        versionName project.versionName
    }
    ...
}
```

Fails with :

```
2021-08-17T20:45:10.644+1000 [QUIET] [system.out] key=versionName value=21.1.3-SNAPSHOT
2021-08-17T20:45:10.645+1000 [QUIET] [system.out] key=versionCode value=21001003
2021-08-17T20:45:10.645+1000 [QUIET] [system.out] project.versionCode=21001003
2021-08-17T20:45:10.645+1000 [QUIET] [system.out] project.versionName=21.1.3-SNAPSHOT
2021-08-17T20:45:10.645+1000 [QUIET] [system.out] project.ext.versionCode=21001003
2021-08-17T20:45:10.646+1000 [QUIET] [system.out] project.ext.versionName=21.1.3-SNAPSHOT
...
2021-08-17T20:45:10.690+1000 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] 
2021-08-17T20:45:10.690+1000 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
2021-08-17T20:45:10.690+1000 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] 
2021-08-17T20:45:10.690+1000 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * Where:
2021-08-17T20:45:10.690+1000 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] Build file 'C:\Source\wylas\wirelesstiming\android-apps\timekeeper\build.gradle' line: 21
2021-08-17T20:45:10.690+1000 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] 
2021-08-17T20:45:10.690+1000 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * What went wrong:
2021-08-17T20:45:10.690+1000 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] A problem occurred evaluating project ':timekeeper'.
2021-08-17T20:45:10.690+1000 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] > No signature of method: build_59ns6w30vg653ob1t6cfszcra.android() is applicable for argument types: (build_59ns6w30vg653ob1t6cfszcra$_run_closure3) values: [build_59ns6w30vg653ob1t6cfszcra$_run_closure3@3eb0b9d1]
2021-08-17T20:45:10.690+1000 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] 
2021-08-17T20:45:10.690+1000 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * Try:
2021-08-17T20:45:10.690+1000 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.  Run with --scan to get full insights.
2021-08-17T20:45:10.691+1000 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] 
2021-08-17T20:45:10.691+1000 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
2021-08-17T20:45:10.691+1000 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildResultLogger] 
2021-08-17T20:45:10.691+1000 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildResultLogger] BUILD FAILED in 1s
```

This answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/29597784/493682 suggests that what I am trying to do should work.

How can configure the *versionCode* and *versionName* attributes so that they take the values from *project.ext.versionCode* and *project.ext.versionName* respectively.

Why am I getting the failure and what does that error mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem is that `Properties` are readed as `String` ...

so `project.versionCode` is a `String` and `android.defaultConfig.versionCode` expects to get integer

solution is to use

```
defaultConfig {
   versionCode project.versionCode.toInteger()
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Selvin. I wish the Gradle error message was more precise. I doubt whether I would have found that on my own.

Answer (score 1):

Try reading `versionName` & `versionCode` from your file like this:

```
defaultConfig {

    //...

    Properties buildProperties = new Properties()
    buildProperties.load(new FileInputStream(rootProject.file("build.properties")))

    versionName buildProperties.versionName
    versionCode Integer.parseInt(buildProperties.versionCode)

    // ...
}
```

Where `build.properties` file is placed in your project's root directory.

Comment: @Selvin I actually checked the code from my project and update the answer after I saw that I've missed converting to int part.

Comment: Thanks for a simpler way of reading the properties file.

Answer (score 0):

For `build.gradle.kts`

```kotlin
task("printVersionName") {
  doLast {
    println("version-${android.defaultConfig.versionCode}")
  }
}

task("printVersionCode") {
  doLast { println("build-${android.defaultConfig.versionCode}") }
}
```

For `build.gradle`

```
task printVersionName {
    doLast {
        println "version-$android.defaultConfig.versionName"
    }
}

task printVersionCode {
    doLast {
        println "build-$android.defaultConfig.versionCode"
    }
}
```